# WCT GetThreadWaitChain call allways return false

Tags: c#, multithreading, pinvoke

I am trying to get WCT information about some thread, but every time I am calling GetThreadWaitChain function I am getting false as a response and the ref parameters remain zero.

What am I doing wrong?

I am calling this function on a thread which calls WaitForMultipleObjects, and I am making sure that this thread waits while I am debugging.

That's my code:

```
    internal void CollectWaitInformation(ClrThread thread)
    {
        var g_WctHandle = OpenThreadWaitChainSession(0, 0);

        uint threadID = thread.OSThreadId;

        WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[] NodeInfoArray = new WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[WCT_MAX_NODE_COUNT];


        int isCycle = 0;
        int count = 0;

        // Make a synchronous WCT call to retrieve the wait chain.
        bool result = GetThreadWaitChain(g_WctHandle,
                                IntPtr.Zero,
                                WCTP_GETINFO_ALL_FLAGS,
                                threadID, ref count, NodeInfoArray, out isCycle);

        if (!result)
        {
            //error
        }

        //Finaly ...
        CloseSession(g_WctHandle);
    }

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenThreadWaitChainSession(OpenThreadChainFlags Flags, DWORD callback);

    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetThreadWaitChain(
        IntPtr WctHandle,
        IntPtr Context,
        UInt32 Flags,
        uint ThreadId,
        ref int NodeCount,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)]
        [In, Out]
        WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[] NodeInfoArray,
        out int IsCycle
    );

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO
    {
        public WCT_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;
        public WCT_OBJECT_STATUS ObjectStatus;

        public struct LockObject
        {
            string ObjectName;
            LARGE_INTEGER Timeout;
            BOOL Alertable;
        }
        public struct ThreadObject
        {
            DWORD ProcessId;
            DWORD ThreadId;
            DWORD WaitTime;
            DWORD ContextSwitches;
        }
    }
}
```

}

With a help from my previous question:

[Calling C++ method from C# with pointer parameter (WCT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020727/calling-c-method-from-c-sharp-with-pointer-parameter-wct)

Comment: Please read the documentation. You simply cannot attempt to use a library without reading the documentation first. When you read the documentation you'll learn how to handle errors. It's going to involve `SetLastError = true` in the `DllImport` attributes, and calls to `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` in case of failure. Or indeed `throw new Win32Exception()` in case of failure.

Comment: I did call GetLastError function, and I;ve got 87 as a result is it an ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER error? Accordingly to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx system error doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> *NodeCount [in, out]*
>
> On input, a number from 1 to WCT_MAX_NODE_COUNT that specifies the number of nodes in the wait chain. On return, the number of nodes retrieved.
>
> ....

You fail to meet this requirement because you pass in 0.

Comment: I'm getting a result now. I've tried to follow the C++ example of WCT usage but somehow I've missed it. Thank you

Comment: Adding the error checking helps narrow the field of possible causes. Always check for errors carefully.

Comment: My visual studio hangs as I am calling GetThreadWaitChain function do you know what can it be? I get this message: vhhost32.exe has stopped working