# Visual Studio hangs on GetThreadWaitChain WCT call

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, pinvoke, freeze

I am trying out WCT and I want to call GetThreadWaitChain, I had some previous questions on this topic, but I've got recently strange behavior. As I am calling `GetThreadWaitChain` fuction my Visual Studio hangs with prompt message:

> vhost32.exe has stopped working

Output windows message:

```
The program '[9068] testWCT.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374).
```

Every time I am getting to that function my visual studio hangs...

GetThreadWaitChain documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679364(v=vs.85).aspx

This is my code:

```
internal void CollectWaitInformation(ClrThread thread)
{
    var g_WctHandle = OpenThreadWaitChainSession(0, 0);

    uint threadID = thread.OSThreadId;

    WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[] NodeInfoArray = new WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[16];


    int isCycle = 0;
    int count = 16;

    // Make a synchronous WCT call to retrieve the wait chain.
    bool result = GetThreadWaitChain(g_WctHandle,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            WCTP_GETINFO_ALL_FLAGS,
                            threadID, ref count, NodeInfoArray, out isCycle);

    if (!result)
    {
        //error
    }

    //Finaly ...
    CloseSession(g_WctHandle);
}

[DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenThreadWaitChainSession(OpenThreadChainFlags Flags, DWORD callback);

[DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetThreadWaitChain(
    IntPtr WctHandle,
    IntPtr Context,
    UInt32 Flags,
    uint ThreadId,
    ref int NodeCount,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 4)]
    [In, Out]
    WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[] NodeInfoArray,
    out int IsCycle
);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO
{
    public WCT_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;
    public WCT_OBJECT_STATUS ObjectStatus;

    public struct LockObject
    {
        string ObjectName;
        LARGE_INTEGER Timeout;
        BOOL Alertable;
    }
    public struct ThreadObject
    {
        DWORD ProcessId;
        DWORD ThreadId;
        DWORD WaitTime;
        DWORD ContextSwitches;
    }
}
```

}

I've tried to run C++ code on the same process, which I took from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681418(v=vs.85).aspx

And all I've got is: 0x57 error on all threads as a result. Which is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER accordingly to MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Which is weird cause I didn't changed the C++ code..

Previous question on the same topic:
[WCT GetThreadWaitChain call allways return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139351/wct-getthreadwaitchain-call-allways-return-false)

Comment: 0xc0000374 is a heap corruption error code.  Plenty of memory corruption in this code, your WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO declaration is not accurate and far too small.  Declaring a struct that contains a union with a string is very little fun, do this in a C++/CLI project instead.

Comment: Where did you get 0xc0000374 error?

Comment: You posted it, the exit code of a process that is terminated by the OS is the exception code.

Comment: First time that I've seen GC heap corruption produce 0xc0000374.  This normally bombs with ExecutionEngineException.  Must be new .NET 4.6.x behavior.  Well, one for the record book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I declared the WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO struct in a wrong way (my union was wrong) this is the original structure:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681422(v=vs.85).aspx

As soon as I declared it right, the heap corruption stopped and everything worked...