# WCT GetThreadWaitChain function call as async causes process hang

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to call `Advapi32` `GetThreadWaitChain` (WCT) function from my c# code, I've struggled previously on similar issue:
[WCT GetThreadWaitChain call allways return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139351/wct-getthreadwaitchain-call-allways-return-false)

However now I am trying to make this call as async call with callback, as documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681421(v=vs.85).aspx

That's my finction:

```
internal void CollectWaitAsyncInformation(ClrThread thread)
{   
    //Currenlty not working
    var handle = Advapi32.OpenThreadWaitChainSession(WCT_SESSION_OPEN_FLAGS.WCT_ASYNC_OPEN_FLAG, AppCallback);

    uint threadID = thread.OSThreadId;

    WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[] NodeInfoArray = new WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO[WctApiConst.WCT_MAX_NODE_COUNT];

    int isCycle = 0;
    int Count = WctApiConst.WCT_MAX_NODE_COUNT;

    _eventHandler = Kernel32.CreateEvent(IntPtr.Zero, true, true, "MyEvent");

    //This is where the applciation hangs
    bool waitChainResult = Advapi32.GetThreadWaitChain(handle,
                            _eventHandler, 0 ,
                            threadID, ref Count, NodeInfoArray, out isCycle);

    CheckCount(ref Count);

    if (!waitChainResult)
    {

        var lastErrorCode = WinApi.Advapi32.GetLastError();

        if (lastErrorCode == (uint)SYSTEM_ERROR_CODES.ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            // Wait for callback to run...
            WinApi.Kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(_eventHandler, int.MaxValue);
        }
        Kernel32.WaitForSingleObject(_eventHandler, uint.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

link:

https://github.com/Pavel-Durov/Multithreading-Debugging-Asignments/blob/master/Assignments/Assignments.Core/Handlers/WCT/WctApiHandler.cs

My process hangs as I am calling `Advapi32.GetThreadWaitChain` function without any error or such.

Last time the problem was with the `WAITCHAIN_NODE_INFO` struct layout, however here I am using the same struct so I don't know if it is an issue, but if I pass `IntPtr.Zero` instead on `NodeInfo` array I get false as a result but `GetLastError` returns me 0.

Any help will be appreciated :).

Here is the link for my whole GitHub project:
https://github.com/Pavel-Durov/Multithreading-Debugging-Asignments

Comment: You shouldn't call the winapi GetLastError(), and should instead mark the function import as `SetLastError = true`. Then throw a Win32Exception if you want to get at the error info. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx

Comment: Ok, I'll change it, but the hang happens before the GetLastError call...